# Define Colorbox while Error Message: "Missing number, treated as zero."

Tags: colorbox

I'm trying to create a new colorbox like this:[image]

And I copied the code :

```
% -----formula
    \newtcolorbox{formula}[][]{breakable,enhanced,
    colback=goldenyellow!5,colframe=goldenyellow,coltitle=black,
    title=\faLightbulb \hspace{0.2cm} formula,top=2mm,boxsep=3mm,
    attach boxed title to top left=
    {yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2 ,xshift=0.3cm},
    boxed title style={size=small,colback=goldenyellow}}
```

I had defined the color like "golden yellow" yet[image].
Error Message:
[image]
I had work all night so how to fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of `\newtcolorbox` is

```
\newtcolorbox[⟨init options⟩]{⟨name⟩}[⟨number⟩][⟨default⟩]{⟨options⟩}
```

The first optional argument after the name is the number of mandatory arguments and *cannot* be left empty. TeX expects a number, and if you give no number then you'll clearly get a `Missing number` error. It would be the same if you wrote

```
\newcommand*{\foo}[]{...}
```

Just remove the empty optional arguments

```
\newtcolorbox{formula}{...}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works!!